# How can I make my drop down menu allign to the left with my header?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

How can I make the submenu to align to the left side of the header??

I have tried `.dropdown-menu-left.` in the `<ul>` but it doesn't work.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
   <div class="mainMenu">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-sura" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <a href="" class="Logo-Small"></a>
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
               <div class="container">
                  <a href=""class="Logo"></a>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                     <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Seguros para Autos</a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                           <li class="pruebamenu"><a href="#">Seguros para Autos</a></li>
                           <li class="pruebamenu"><a href="#">Centros de servicio</a></li>
                           <li class="pruebamenu"><a href="#">Asistencia</a></li>
                           <li class="pruebamenu"><a href="#">Te damos más</a></li>
                           <li class="pruebamenu"><a href="#">Acompañamiento satelital</a></li>
                           <li class="pruebamenu"><a href="#">Formación</a></li>
                           <li class="pruebamenu"><a href="#">Aliados</a></li>
                           <li class="pruebamenu"><a href="#">Promociones</a></li>
                        </ul>

                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
            </div>
         </nav>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your screen capture, but the dropdown might be doing that because the dropdown is near the right edge of the browser's viewport - Bootstrap 3 now "intelligently" positions tooltips and popovers inside the viewport if it detects it will render outside the browser's viewport. I suspect the same is true for dropdowns.

Comment: Thank you Joyrex. It happens with the first option of the menu as well and it is not near the edge of the browser's viewport. I edited the question with the code.

Comment: Ah - well, the Bootstrap Documentation is always a good place to start - I would make sure the code you have in place for the menu matches the example found here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar - it looks like from your screenshot there is some positioning issues with the dropdown aligning to the bottom of the navbar too.

Answer (score 0):

This made happen the alignment to the right:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

I've changed to:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
```

:)